# comparing Sqlite records to python variables

Tags: python, sqlite

This is a continuation from my last problem. I want the program to print correct email when the email is the same as one of my emails in my db database but even though they are the same the program still thinks they are different. Also I have tried putting c.fetchall() into a variable and then replacing it with that in my if statement but that still doesn't work. This will eventually be paired with PyQt so when I press a button it will run this part of the code. Finally I am a Mac user so this might also link with the problem but I am not sure

This is my code. I was expecting the program to print correct email as check is the same as c.fetchall() but it isn't.

```
import sqlite3
check = "Benclarke2016@hotmail.com"
conn = sqlite3.connect("U+P.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("""SELECT email FROM details WHERE email = ?""",(check, ))
r = c.fetchall()
conn.commit()
check = "[('"+check+"',)]"
print(check)
if r == check:
    print("correct email")
    email = True
else:
    print("incorrect email")
conn.close()
```

Comment: Why are you comparing your email to `fetchall` and not the values returned by accessing the cursor? This is much easier for comparing as you'd be comparing a string with a string

Comment: Ok so how would I turn the values returned into a string? sometimes it returns the cursors' location and not a string I can use

Comment: Something like: `data = c.fetchall()` then `for row in data: if row[index] == check: print('yay')`...index will be a number of the column index your email row is located